# Using Android Emulator to emulate a phone with Droid spec

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to use the android dev emualtor to create a virtual phone with the same spec as the droid.

I am using the WVGA 854 profile, High deinsity (240) and scaling the emulator screen to 3.7 inch on launch.

Problem is it seems to be emulating it like it has WVGA 854 resolution but with a medium or low density screen, as the icons are teeny tiny and the whole thing looks wrong.

Im sure the droid does have teeny tiny icons and apps, can anyone tell me where i am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Skin for the [Droid](http://teavuihuang.com/android/) and install it into the sdk skins director.

Comment: works great, thanks. Even know the settigns look the same as what i said above, it actually displays at the correct size now, thank you!